# XML tag format issue in c#

Tags: c#, xml, rss

Am using below code to generate XML file from RSS feed URL, but data is not showing in tag format in XML file.

In XML file `<` symbol showing as`&lt;` and `>` symbol showing like `&gt;`

Please help me on this. This is my code.

```
public bool DownloadFeed(){

    string user = "xxx";
    string password = "pwd";

    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, password);
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
                                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                                        SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    wc.DownloadFile(@"https://Entered RSS Feed URL here", @"H:\import\Test.xml");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although another answer has already been accepted, there is nothing wrong with your code, and the offered answer isn't actually helping you. And just to be clear, I'm not criticizing Alex, who had no chance of working this out, since the relevant information had not been provided (but it is in the OP's [next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165926/how-to-remove-nbsp-nowrap-in-xml-file-using-c-sharp) and [subsequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168925/how-to-add-end-tag-to-image-tag-in-xml-file-using-c-sharp) questions). Preethi, you are simply misunderstanding what you are looking at in the downloaded RSS file.

[RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) is an XML-based format. Take a look at the [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Example) on that page, because it uses plain text. The file you are downloading will be in that format. But I am guessing (based on this question and your next two questions on the same subject) that the RSS file that you are pointing at contains HTML in the data rather than plain text.

The problem is that HTML uses `<` and `>` quite a lot, so you will have noticed that it does something odd with them - it turns them into `&lt;` and `&gt;`. It has to do this because the value containing the HTML is within the XML definition of the RSS file.

Let me use an analogy... It's very similar to the problem you have when you want to create a string containing a double-quote. Strings use double-quotes as terminators, so you *can't* do:

```
string hello="hello"world";
```

because C# sees the opening double-quote and then goes looking for the closing double-quote, and it finds the one after the word `hello`. So you have to *escape* that character so that it realises that this isn't the end of the string. You have to do:

```
string hello="hello\"world";
```

The same kind of thing applies with XML. XMLs format is entirely dependent on `<` and `>` characters (amongst other things). So if I had some XML saying:

```
<item>
  <title>Example entry</title>
</item>
```

that would be fine; but if I simply replaced the plain text of "Example entry" with a piece of HTML:

```
<item>
  <title><html><td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=20% valign=top></html></title>
</item>
```

Then it would be a problem, because the value inside the `title` tag is going to cause problems. One problem is that it is not *well-formed* XML (e.g. because there is no closing `td` tag and the attributes do not have to be quoted; because HTML is **not** XML). Another problem is that doing this would break the definition of the RSS format, because the "title" tag should contain a value, not other tags. So we need to *escape* the value within the title tag as follows:

```
<item>
  <title>&lt;html&gt;&lt;td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=20% valign=top&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</title>
</item>
```

And this will be the kind of thing that you're seeing within your RSS file.

So I believe the answer you were actually looking for was that you need to process the RSS file that you get back as an XML file (try using [XmlDocument.Load(uri)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807(v=vs.110).aspx) or [XDocument.Load(uri)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181(v=vs.110).aspx) with the URL of your RSS feed.

Once you have it as an XML document, and you look through the values in the RSS file, you will see that the values have correctly been decoded from the XML escaping, so the HTML values will actually look like HTML, without any need to decode anything.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your string in file is sanitized. You can download it as string, decode and then save to the file:

```
var xmlString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(wc.DownloadString(@"https://Entered RSS Feed URL here"));
File.WriteAllText(@"H:\import\Test.xml", xmlString);
```

Comment: Thanks for u r reply. I tried with above line but i got 'Severity Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable' and 'No overload for method 'DownloadFile' takes 1 argument errors. Please help

Comment: @Preethi sorry, I made a mistake, should be DownloadString instead of DownloadFile, I updated post, could you try one more time?

Comment: Thanks Alex. Working fine. Can you please tell me what is the exact  problem in my code?